# The different between Request and Array To obtain an instance HTTP Request ? - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Why some other people using `Array` instead `Request`to obtained incoming Request instance.

Ex array: 
`public function create(array $data)`
Ex Request:
`public function create(Request $request)`

So my question is.. is it different ? 
When to use `Array` or `Request` ? 
different between `Array` and `Request` ?

Comment: I've never seen someone use the `array $data` approach, and doing so causes a 500 error when I test it. Can you link to an example of it in use?

Answer (score 1):

`Request` is a class made to handle HTTP requests, and it have some very nice methods to handle the input data coming from forms or requests. Like the magic method way of accessing form fields `$request->email`. Then it have some really cool functions like:

```php
$request->url();
// OR
$request->isMethod('post');
```

and too many others. A list of the cool functions is listed in the laravel documentation. I suggest reading the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests).

While taking the Array there to handle your request you will have to use traditional php way of accessing your request fields. like:

```php
$name = $arrayRequest['name'];
$email = $arrayRequest['email'];
```

etc.